# How to fix "Access denied" on opening image url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I finally managed to upload some images to my s3 bucket but I can't open them. If I navigate to them in my bucket i get "object URL" but every time I try to open it I get:

```
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Access Denied</Message>
 <RequestId>7F4BB573F589D927</RequestId>
 <HostId>GkYjQGNkrh84HodCaQxfTHKFCDLle82B5d4oa6EyeK1ZJMt/BeZG09eS2CIiR6Ri2Va/IvQIcIE=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I added bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1547051060680",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1547051055882",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name06/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: check permissions tab on the bucket and make sure the access control policy has sufficient permissions(Read object, write object). If not, add them then you will be able to see the objects in the bucket

Comment: Do you mean bucket>permissions>Access control list >public access? I tried adding access here but I get "Access denied" when I try to save it :\

Comment: Public access is usually not recommended.  There are 2 other access levels too: your account and other aws account. do you have read and write permissions enabled on your account level(if reading from same account otherwise put your canonical aws id in account of others).

Comment: Also, it looks like you don't have permission in corresponding aws account. Have you created the aws account or using a group account where permissions are managed by posix groups or something else?

Comment: In "Access for your AWS account root user" tab I have all permissions

Comment: Not sure what are you asking about :\ I created my account.....by creating it :\

Comment: did you upload image using sdk or console? did you set acl 'public-read'?

Comment: Using sdk. I didn't

Comment: I'm trying to find where should I set this acl

Comment: putObject has Acl property where you need to set 'public-read'. Default is private

Comment: I set "Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects" to false and gave public access to list objects. Can I leave it like that?

Comment: That acl property doesn't work :\

Comment: I also needed to set "Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies" to false to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bucket policy is already public so you don't need to modify anything in the policy. You need to set ACL property to 'public-read' when using PutObject API. Also, don't leave bucket policy public assign it a policy to restrict upload.

Comment: That doesn't work :\ What does work is setting "Block new public ACLs and uploading public objects" to false and giving public access to list objects. Can I leave it like that?

Comment: I also needed to set "Block public and cross-account access if bucket has public policies" to false to make it work

Comment: I won't suggest you to do that instead create an IAM role policy for the application user. If app is publicly available then use PreSignedUrl to generate signed url to allow anonymous user upload the image but never make your bucket public.

Comment: I don't know anything about Iam roles, how to create them and I don't really have time for that....so for now I'm gonna leave it like that and fix it later.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give your IAM role, that you are using to access the account, read permissions to the bucket. You can do an attach policy or in json it can look something like this

```
 {
            "Sid": "S3Read",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name06",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name06/*"
            ]
 }
```

Assuming the s3 bucket is on the same account as the IAM role you are trying to access you do not need to enable cross account access. If they are not, you will need to allow on the bucket side for the IAM role to read the bucket.

If you need write access you can do something similar to this

```
{
            "Sid": "S3Write",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Put*",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name06",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name06/*"
            ]
}
```

Comment: I added the first one to my bucket policy and it changes nothing. It also looks pointless to me because I'm not using any IAM user when I try to open image in browser simply using url link

Comment: are you using aws cli or aws console or are you literally just clicking your s3 url to view the information...

you need to go through the cli or through the console.

Comment: either use the aws cli with federeated access or go directly through the console.